First derived push-forward along birational morphism
Let $X$ being a smooth variety of dimension $2$ over a field of positive characteristic.
Let $X \xrightarrow{f} Y$ be a birational morphism (say blowdown of negative self-intersection curves), and take an effective Cartier divisor $D$ on $X$, which contains multiples of (some of?) the blown-down curves.
What does $R^1f_*\mathcal O_X(-D)$ look like? What about $H^1(R^1f_*\mathcal O_X(-D))$?
There is a similar question here. I'm wondering what this looks like in this more general case.
